# How to receive the output from /usr/bin/time -v?

Tags: python, time, subprocess

I have implemented an algorithm in C++ and inside the implementation I count some statistics, like cache misses, instructions, branch misses etc. This information is printed in the end with `cout`.  However I would also like to know how much space the implementation is using. I use `subprocess` as follows:

```
result = subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/time', '-v','./program',input])
```

unfortunately only the output from `./program` is stored in `result` and not the output of `/usr/bin/time` as well. Here is one possible output from `/usr/bin/time`:

```
User time (seconds): 3.41
    System time (seconds): 0.06
    Percent of CPU this job got: 99%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:03.48
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 344016
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 72338
    Voluntary context switches: 1
    Involuntary context switches: 6
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

I am only interested in `Maximum resident set size (kbytes):`. If I could somehow store this big text inside `result`, then I was hoping that I could parse it. But the output is not stored at all in `result`, it is simply printed. What is the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time` outputs to STDERR, so you need to redirect that to STDOUT, or capture it separately. From the [`time` command manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time):

> When *command* finishes, **time** ***writes a message to standard error*** giving timing statistics about this program run.

***Bold italic*** emphasis mine.

Redirecting is done with `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`:

```
result = subprocess.check_output(
    ['/usr/bin/time', '-v', './program', input],
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

or use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) to capture the two streams separately:

```
result = subprocess.run(
    ['/usr/bin/time', '-v', './program', input],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout = result.stdout
time_output = result.stderr
```

`subprocess.run()` is new in Python 3.5 and up; use [`subprocess.Popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) directly if you have an older Python version (and consider upgrading ASAP):

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    ['/usr/bin/time', '-v', './program', input],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, time_output = process.communicate()
```